# Different benches in bench press

Tags: bench-press

What are the pro's and con's of a bench which is softer (i.e. has more cusions) than one with a harder surface?

Answer (score 3):

A softer bench would absorb more energy, this would mean less power transfer. The soft surface would basically be a barrier between you and the bench, and at heavier weights would cause you to lift less. Maybe not to an extreme but less weight none the less. Always choose a firm bench.